# pass the output of a batch file into a for loop

Tags: for-loop, input, batch-file, output, readline

I am trying to pass the output of a process into a for loop by using pipes

```
type %1% | findstr /R /V "Test" | for /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('more') DO @echo %%i
```

but I do not know what to put in place of ('more') so that it reads the output from the findstr command. Is this even possible? Or do I have to save the output to a file and then read in the file in an entirely different batch program? Please help.

Comment: change `%1%` to `%1` or to handle quotes properly use `"%~1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /rv "Test" "%1%" ^| more') do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops cannot read from `STDIN`, so you need to put the command whose output you want to process into the parantheses:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('type %1% ^| findstr /R /V "Test"') DO @echo %%i
```

Note that pipes must be escaped in the subshell (`^|`).